# Is it possible to change project ip address in google cloud console or firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Some of my projects in my firebase account are blocked by ip address in my country. I guess thats was happened, in case of blocking some google resources that uses same ip address. For now, i have website in my firebase account: oneday.tv. Its domain name has ping for: 199.36.158.100. I can access to it only through vpn. Some projects in same firebase account works ok, because they has different ip. In firebase support told me, that it's the reason of government decision. Can i change ip address for existing projects in my firebase console or google cloud console? Even if i tried to create brand new firebase project, its gets this ip address 199.36.158.100. May be there is a way to get another ip address for new project?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. The reason you are getting the same IP address is that address is the Google Frontend's IP address. You cannot change that.

You would need to switch to a service that supports external IP addresses such as Compute Engine. However, you cannot select a specific address, just the one Google selects from an available address pool, so it is a coin toss if that address would be blocked.